# Returning Keys and Values from Array

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone please help me out with that one. I'm getting the locale of Facebook page fans. The output from Facebook is in JSON format. After I `json_decode($fb_output)` I end up with array below. I'd like to echo a list with the top 10 languages (or all if there are less than 10) and the value in the key(number of people who speak that language). So far I've unsuccessfully tried to get it with `foreach ($fb_output $key => $value)`

Here is the array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [value] => stdClass Object ( 
        [de_DE] => 8527 
        [en_US] => 313 
        [en_GB] => 147 
        [tr_TR] => 106 
        [it_IT] => 79 
        [sr_RS] => 25 
        [hu_HU] => 24 
        [es_ES] => 15 
        [bs_BA] => 12 
        [es_LA] => 12 
        [sk_SK] => 11 
        [ro_RO] => 10 
        [ru_RU] => 9 
        [pt_BR] => 9 
        [nl_NL] => 8 
        [hr_HR] => 8 
        [fr_FR] => 7 
        [sv_SE] => 5 
        [cs_CZ] => 5 
        [bg_BG] => 5 
        ) 
    [end_time] => 2012-03-05T08:00:00+0000 ) )
```

The number of keys in this array varies from user to user so it'd need to be flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$topTen = array_slice(array_keys( (array) $fb_output[0]->value ), 0, 10);
```

What it does:

1. Transforms the stdClass Object into an native array. (`(array)` operator)
2. Turns that array into another array, containing only its keys. (`array_keys()` function)
3. Extracts the first ten entries of that array. (`array_slice()` function)

If you want to extract the top ten including their values, skip the `array_keys` part and make sure, that the keys of the array don't get mixed up while slicing it (4th parameter of that function, see the docs for more information):

```
$topTen = array_slice( (array) $fb_output[0]->value, 0, 10, true);
echo $topTen['en_GB']; // 147
```

Comment: Hi @Niko, thanks for that - very helpful and educating. Would you know how to get the values with that as well? So that i end up with a list of top ten languages and the value to each language (how many people speak that language).

Comment: Sure, I added a paragraph about that to my answer.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot @Niko - works like a charm. This is the output: Array ( [de_DE] => 8527 [en_US] => 313 [en_GB] => 147 [tr_TR] => 106 [it_IT] => 79 [sr_RS] => 25 [hu_HU] => 24 [es_ES] => 15 [bs_BA] => 12 [es_LA] => 12 )

Now I'm just trying to echo on per line because I'm feeding it to a bar chart. For a PHP newbie like me, echoing an array like this is quite a task ;)

Comment: Congratulations ;) You might wanna check the docs at http://php.net/array for a lot more information and array related functions, that php provides you with by default. Echoing that array is now an easy thing to do, you can simply use a loop: `foreach ($topTen as $lang => $visitors)`